# An extension of the Utilities Problem. (for $n$ utilities) I want to find sufficient conditions to make it work.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, topological-graph-theory, graph-minors

We know that the Utility Problem asks to connect three utilities to three houses without crossing utilities line. I can prove that there is no solution in the plane or $S^2$, but it is solvable on torus.

But, if we're given utilities $U_1, U_2,\dotsc, U_m$ and houses $H_1,H_2, \dotsc, H_n$ located on a sphere with $g$ handles. How can we quickly find necessary and sufficient conditions for $m$, $n$, $g$, so that this problem can be solved?

I tried to start with simple situation but it becomes too complicated as I increase the value of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: I'm suspicious that this might be a *hard problem*. In general it's hard to classify which graphs can be embedded on a genus $g$ surface. In the planar case, the problem only has a solution if there are at most 2 utilities or 2 houses, which is due to the fact that the [complete bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph) $K_{3,3}$ is non-planar. But [$K_{3,3}$ can be embedded on a torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_graph). So I'm curious, if there are now 4 utilities and 3 houses, have you found if this has a solution on the torus?

Comment: 4 houses and 4 utilities (Water, Gas, Electricity, Internet) is possible on a Torus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ (which is the graph for the problem with $m$ utilities that must all be connected to $n$ houses) requires adding $$\gamma(K_{m,n}) = \left\lceil \frac{(m-2)(n-2)}{4} \right\rceil$$ handles to the plane (or, equivalently, to the sphere) before it can be embedded, according to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphGenus.html); the original citation is in German [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02993245.pdf) (Gerhard Ringel, "Das Geschlecht des vollständigen paaren Graphen").

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, I think now I have a better visualization about this problem after studying topology. I'll try to solve it. :)